# Create multiple elements and delete a single one JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a JavaScript project where a user can click a button to create a text element. However, I also want a feature where I can click a different button and the element that was created most recently will be removed, so In other words, I want to be able to click a button to create an element and click a different button to undo that action.

The problem I was having was that I created the element, then I would remove the element using:
`element.parentNode.removeChild(element);` , but it would clear all of the elements that were created under the same variable.

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");               
elem.innerText = "Text";                
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

This code allows an element to be created with a button click. All elemente that would be created are under the "elem" variable. so when I remove the element "elem", all element are cleared. 
Is there a simple way to remove on element at a time that were all created procedurally?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Put a class on them, grab all of them by the class, get the last one, and then remove it.

Comment: "_it would clear all of the elements that were created under the same variable_" Nope, it would clear only the last created element, in that variable you can store a single value at the time, it can't hold multiple values.

Comment: A screenshot would be great, since there are different opinions regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the elements, give the a `class`. When you want to remove an element, just get the last element by the `className` and remove it.

The below snippet demonstrates it -

```js
for(let i = 0; i<5; i++){
  var elem = document.createElement("div");               
  elem.innerText = "Text " + i;
  elem.className = "added";
  document.body.appendChild(elem); 
}

setTimeout(function(){
  var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("added");
  var lastDiv = allDivs.length-1;
  document.body.removeChild(allDivs[lastDiv]);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `querySelector`s to grab the last element:

```js
// optional
// this is not needed it's just a random string added as
// content so we can see that the last one is removed
function uid() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
}

document.querySelector('#add')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.textContent = `Text #${uid()}`;

    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(elem);
    // optional - if there are elements to remove, 
    // enable the undo button
    document.querySelector('#undo').removeAttribute('disabled');
  });

document.querySelector('#undo')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // grab the last child and remove
    document.querySelector('#container > div:last-child').remove();

    // optional - if there are no more divs we disable the undo button
    if (document.querySelectorAll('#container > div').length === 0) {
      document.querySelector('#undo').setAttribute('disabled', '');
    }
  });
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="undo" disabled>Undo</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```